# MYSQL IN ordering DESC or random?

Tags: php, mysql

Is the ordering of the numbers in the WHERE xxx IN xxx important?

I mean, is (ordered lowest to highest):

```
SELECT this FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1,3,54,778,98456)
```

Faster than (random ordering):

```
SELECT this FROM table1 WHERE id IN (3,778,54,98456,1)
```

The id is the primary key of table1, and is int(11).

Comment: Did you already try [`EXPLAIN` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference.

An IN with a list of numbers is evaluated like:

```
id IN (3,778,54,98456,1)
```

becomes

```
id = 3 OR id = 778 OR id = 54 OR id = 98456 OR id = 1
```

If the IN was a subquery, then *indexes* matter because this is form of JOIN (semi-join), whereas a static IN list is simply a shorthand for a series or OR filters

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is smart enough to figure out the "best" way to use your `IN`, it might sort it for you if that makes it better for it, and this is going to be a cheap operation (not as cheap as doing nothing though, but almost, unless your `IN` list is huge). In terms of SQL standard, the order has absolutely no importance (it'll not change the result, that is), so you could put them in any order.

I generally like having them sorted in ascending order, more for style reasons than performance itself, I find it makes it easier to maintain the list.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it may save a few cycles if you order the values in the order the database is sorted. However, you'd have to sort them, which takes extra cycles :-) I'd say that not using sort() is faster.